# Can Angular use capture rather than bubbling to catch events?

Tags: angular

I somehow need capture method to catch triggered events, but ($event) in template is triggered in bubbling method by default. Is there somewhere to change it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Currently this can only be done adding event handlers imperatively.

There are plans though to support that in the future

See

- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11200
- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/13371
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13248

Comment: Thank you so much, I have found a workaround with inspirations of your links.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: @Liranius, could you share your solution?

Comment: Does Angular (5+) support "capture" on click event now?

Comment: I don't think so. I didn't work with Angular the last 6 months and don't follow that closely what's happening but I couldn't find anything in https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md and above issues are still open.

Comment: the angular still has no support for capturing phase :(

Answer (score 8):

One workaround is to use the naive approach and add an event listener in your component's constructor.

Then add 'true' as the 3rd parameter to achieve event capturing.

```
constructor() {

    document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {

      console.log(event);

    }, true);

}
```

Tip: use the fat arrow function to reference the correct 'this'

Answer (score 2):

You can create an observable with RxJS

```
this.documentScroll$ = fromEvent(document, 'scroll', { capture: true });
```

And subscribe to it to capture the event.

```
this.documentScroll$.subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
});
```