# HostListener onBlur and onFocus not getting fired in angular4

Tags: angular

I have a written a directive in angular 4 that captures onFocus and onBlur. I can see that my directive gets initialized when the form is loaded but dont see the obBlur or Onfocus firing  when i click the input control. Not sure what is wrong. I have set the ShortNumberFormatterDirective on the input element

directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener, ElementRef, OnInit } from "@angular/core"; 
//import { MyCurrencyPipe } from "./my-currency.pipe"; 


 @Directive({ selector: "[shortNumberFormatter]" }) 
 export class ShortNumberFormatterDirective implements OnInit { 


   private el: HTMLInputElement; 


   constructor( 
     private elementRef: ElementRef, 
    // private currencyPipe: MyCurrencyPipe 
   ) { 
     this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement; 
   } 


   ngOnInit() { 
     //this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value); 
   } 


   @HostListener("focus", ["$event.target.value"]) 
   onFocus(value) { 
     //this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.parse(value); // opossite of transform 
   } 


   @HostListener("blur", ["$event.target.value"]) 
   onBlur(value) { 
     //this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value); 
   } 


 }
```

html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let item of domicileInfo.taxAssesment.items; let last = last; let item_IDX = index">
            <td *ngIf="!last" >
                <click-input   [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMinValid(item,item_IDX) }">
                    <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize"  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged(item,item_IDX)" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> -->
                     <input [(ngModel)]="item.minSize" shortNumberFormatter required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> 
                </click-input>
              </td>

              <td *ngIf="!last">
                  <click-input  [classNames]="{'has-warning': !isMaxValid(item,item_IDX) }">
                      <!-- <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize"  (ngModelChange)="modelChanged(item,item_IDX)" required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> -->
                       <input [(ngModel)]="item.maxSize"   required min="0" max="999999999999999" numberFormat="shortNumberFormat:.0"> 
                  </click-input>
              </td>  
  </tr>
```

Updated code based on Thomas response. If you notice i have written a parse method. The problem that i am facing is , the values are not getting transformed on form initialization. I am seeing the actual number for e.g 20000000 on the screen instead of 20M. I have tried to initialize in the onInit event but the cntrl value seem to be null.

Directive

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ShortNumberFormatPipe } from '../pipes/shortNumberFormat/shortNumberFormat.pipe';

@Directive({ selector: "[shortNumberFormatter]" })
export class ShortNumberFormatterDirective {
    _shortNumberPipe = new ShortNumberFormatPipe();
    get ctrl() {
        return this.ngControl.control;
    }

    constructor(
        private ngControl: NgControl
    ) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.ctrl != null && this.ctrl.value !=null) {
            const x = this._shortNumberPipe.transform(this.ctrl.value);
            console.log(x);
            this.ctrl.setValue(x);
        }
    }


    @HostListener("focus")
    onFocus() {
        const x = this._shortNumberPipe.parse(this.ctrl.value);
        console.log(x);
        this.ctrl.setValue(x);
    }

    @HostListener("blur")
    onBlur() {
        const x = this._shortNumberPipe.transform(this.ctrl.value);
        console.log(x);
        this.ctrl.setValue(x);
    }

}
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'shortNumberFormat'
})
export class ShortNumberFormatPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(number: any, decimals = 0) {

    if (number === null) {
      return;
    }

    number = parseFloat(number);

    if (isNaN(number)) {
      return;
    }

    if (isNaN(decimals)) {
      return;
    }

    const signPrefix = number < 0 ? '-' : '';
    number = Math.abs(number);

    if (number <= 999) { // hundreds
      number = number.toFixed(decimals);
    } else if (number >= 1000 && number <= 999999) {  // thousands
      number = (number / 1000).toFixed(decimals) + 'K';
    } else if (number >= 1000000 && number <= 999999999) { // millions
      number = (number / 1000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'M';
    } else { // billions
      number = (number / 1000000000).toFixed(decimals) + 'B';
    }

    return signPrefix + number;
  }

  parse(inputField: string)
  {
    let parsedNumber: any;

    if(inputField === '')
      return;

    let shortFormatCharector =  inputField.substr(inputField.length - 1);

    switch(shortFormatCharector)
    {
       case'k': 
      parsedNumber = parsedNumber * 1000;
      break; 
    case'M': 
      parsedNumber = parsedNumber * 1000000; 
      break; 
    case'B': 
      parsedNumber = parsedNumber * 1000000000; 
      break; 
    }
    return parsedNumber;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 22):

While there is a `(blur)` output event in Angular components, AFAIK the corresponding event of host listening is not `blur` but `focusout`. So you should rather use:

```
@HostListener("focusout", ["$event.target.value"]) 
onBlur(value) { 
  // ...
}
```

Comment: Just to let anybody know - who comes across this - why that is:  the blur event does not bubble and ``HostListener`` does currently not support event capturing. (see issue links at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43253680/368657)

Comment: To add to @Juarrow "The main difference between this event and focusout is that focusout bubbles while blur does not." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

Comment: You can find the list of events here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focusout_event

Answer (score 9):

If you are planning to use this directive on `<input>` elements, I suggest that you inject the `NgControl` element, and manipulate the `FormControl` directly. It is much cleaner than using the `$event.target.value` approach.

```
import { Directive, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({ selector: "[upperLower]" })
export class UpperLowerDirective {

  get ctrl() {
    return this.ngControl.control;
  }

  constructor(
    private ngControl: NgModel
  ) { }

  @HostListener("focus")
  onFocus() {
    this.ctrl.setValue(this.ctrl.value.toUpperCase());
  }

  @HostListener("blur")
  onBlur() {
    this.ctrl.setValue(this.ctrl.value.toLowerCase());
  }

}
```

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7rbspt)

Comment: i have updated the post to include the way you have suggested but I am not able to parse the values and transform based on the directive

Comment: I tried calling the transform in the  ngAfterViewInit() but the value property is still null. So basically what is happening now is that the first the the page loads the values arent transformed and the value 200000 instead of 20M is getting displayed as result my focus logic fails as i am trying  to parse 2000000 instead of 20M

Comment: Your code doesn't import `NgModel` and doens't use imported `NgControl`