# How to use Captured phase of @HostListener

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular6, angular7, angular2-decorators

I want to use captured phase of @HostListener.

```
@HostListener('document:keydown.escape', ['$event']) onKeydownHandler(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log("key pressed");
  }
```

Above code use default(bubble phase). One of the case I want to use captured phase, please help me, how to use captured phase of @HostListener.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43253099/can-angular-use-capture-rather-than-bubbling-to-catch-events